# DataGrid cell ToolTip based on the column's data

Tags: wpf, tooltip, wpfdatagrid

In my application, i have tried to implement tooltip wich will show me some errors in the datagrid based on the dataGrid Column's text. For sample I have 4 columns with text-boxes for entering some data and if data in the some column doesn't much the rule or if some of them are empty on the last 4th column i should show tooltip with some explanation text.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.02*" IsReadOnly="True">
          <WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type WpfToolkit:DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TransparentCellSelection}">
              <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Value="1">
                  <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowToolTipConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="IsRequired" />
                      <Binding Path="InputColumns.Count" />
                      <Binding Path="HasDefaultValue" />
                      <Binding Path="HasOverwritingValue" />
                      <Binding Path="MappingType" />
                      <Binding Path="SourceColumnMappings" />
                      <Binding Path="ColumnStatus" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </DataTrigger.Binding>
                  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Translation mapping is incomplete." />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Value="2">
                  <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowToolTipConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="IsRequired" />
                      <Binding Path="InputColumns.Count"/>
                      <Binding Path="HasDefaultValue" />
                      <Binding Path="HasOverwritingValue" />
                      <Binding Path="MappingType" />
                      <Binding Path="SourceColumnMappings" />
                      <Binding Path="ColumnStatus" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </DataTrigger.Binding>
                  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Overwriting Value overrides Mapping. Mapping and Default Value are ignored." />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Value="3">
                  <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowToolTipConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="IsRequired" />
                      <Binding Path="InputColumns.Count" />
                      <Binding Path="HasDefaultValue" />
                      <Binding Path="HasOverwritingValue" />
                      <Binding Path="MappingType" />
                      <Binding Path="SourceColumnMappings" />
                      <Binding Path="ColumnStatus" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </DataTrigger.Binding>
                  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Default Value cannot be set for empty Mapping. Please define Mapping or use Overwriting Value instead of Default Value." />
                </DataTrigger>
```

Does anybody know best way to do it?